# Fread returning 0, reading pixels from BMP file

Tags: c, pixel, bmp

I'm using this code to get the pixels from a bmp file. I have already read the headers and the palette in previous lines, so my FILE * is pointing to the beggining of the pixels array.
It reads the first row OK, returns 1000 which is what it should, but when it tries to read the second row of pixels it returns 0.

This is the function that receivs the FILE * , reads the pixels rows and tries to save them into a bmp_type. fila_alineada is the aligned row size, had to do this because of padding.

```
bool leer_pixels_8bpp(   FILE *fbmp, bmp_t *imagen,
                            const uint32_t fila_alineada,
                            const bool btopdown ){
int32_t i;
long x, y;
int32_t height, width, contador;
uint8_t *ptmp;

uint8_t bufferfila[fila_alineada];

height = imagen->infoheader.height;
width  = imagen->infoheader.width;
contador  = height;

i = btopdown ? 1 : -1;
y = btopdown ? 0 : ( height - 1 );

for ( ; contador--; y += i ) /* row loop */
{
    /* reading row */
    if ( fread( bufferfila, sizeof( uint8_t ), fila_alineada, fbmp ) != fila_alineada )
    {    /* HERE is the PROBLEM, it reads ok once, but in the second loop it returns 0 */
        fprintf( stderr, "Error reading pixels row.\n" );
        return false;
    }

    ptmp = bufferfila;
        /* saving pixels into bmp_t */
    for ( x = 0L; x < width; x++ )
    {
        imagen->pixels[y][x] = imagen->paleta.colores[ *ptmp++ ];
    }

}

return true;
```

}

I've tried with differents bmp's! The problem is here or should i consider reviewing the entire code?
Hope someone can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure it returns 0, or it is returning a value different from ``fila_alineada``? If this is the case, then it is expected as the End Of File has been reached...

Comment: Can you comment out the code after if(fread) block ? If the pointer gets corrupted fread may fail.

Comment: Hey guys thanks for the help, ive managed to get it working. 
I was using a switch calling leer_1bpp / 8bpp / 24bpp (3 different functions) depending on which was the file bit per pixel. But i was missing the 'breaks' on each case of the switch.
Dot know how, but it is working now.
I wanted to check debugging it to see fread's value but for some reason kdbg says no symbol fread in current context, before i put those breaks it showed the whole fread(.........) return value.

anyway, it is reading ok since i've put some ftells to see how many bytes it has read and everything goes fine.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems from your code that you are not reading what the `width` of the image is ... rather you are reading an amount of `fila_alineada`.  You mentioned that `fila_alineada` was the aligned row size because of "padding", but BMP files should only have enough padding at the end to extend each row out to a multiple of 4-bytes ... that should be a value though that is easily calculated from the BITMAPINFOHEADER by dividing the actual pixel-array data-size with the number of rows in the image.  The pixel-array data-size is stored at offset 0x22 in the header.  The height, as I'm sure you've correctly deduced, is at offset 0x16.  So the argument `fila_alineada` is pretty much redundant (i.e., you can remove it), and you may be calculating this value incorrectly.  I would simply use the information in the header to calculate the size of the buffer necessary to save the information in a given row of the image.

Secondly, if you simply have tried to copy the BITMAPINFOHEADER information from the file into a buffer that is some representative header structure, keep in mind that the compiler may have padded the structure for byte-alignment purposes ... therefore for safety reasons you should not simply read the entire header from a file and then attempt to use `memcpy()` to write the buffer into a BITMAPINFOHEADER structure.  You should read the header values one-by-one from the file, and store those values individually into any structure that represents the BITMAPINFOHEADER.  Otherwise, if you do the former, by simply trying to read the first N bytes of the file, and copy that into a structure, you could end up, because of byte-alignment issues, copying in values that are incorrect, and therefore all the values you try to read back from that structure will not represent the values associated with your bitmap file.

Comment: Thanks for answering, i've already solve the problem as i said above, anyway i'll answer you! :)

1) I'm using fila_alineada, as i said, to calculate which amount i will have to read per row. If i have a 8bpp bmp, with width of 45pixels, the first row should have 360 bits. As you said, rows size should be of 4 bytes (32 bits). Since 360 is not multiple of 32, what i do is: bitsperrow = width * bitsperpixel
                  if (bitsperrow % 32) 
bitsperrow += 32 - ( bitsperrow % 32 )

Comment: what i do is: bitsperrow = width * bitsperpixel;
                  if (bitsperrow % 32) {
bitsperrow += 32 - ( bitsperrow % 32 ) }
then i divide bitsperrow by 8 to get the bytes quantity on the row(fila_alineada). 
It is just 3 lines! 
And about 2), yes, i was aware of that, the infoheader is not an aligned structure, i had to read first bmp's magic number and then read the other ones and it worked ok. 
I have printed both headers with printf after reading them and they work! 
Thanks again : )

Comment: Your calculations seem good, but just saying, you don't have to jump through those hoops ... simply use the BITMAPINFOHEADER field offset 0x22 to get the number of bytes of pixel data, and then divide by the number of pixel-rows ... that will give you the number of bytes per row without having to calculate any padding offsets.

Comment: You're right, i haven't thought of it... thanks again, i would give you points or something but i'm new here haha.